# Exchange 2013 Internal Relay via Smart Host

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2013

Thank you for your help in advance! I am currently setting up an Exchange 2013 server, to replace our old POP3/SMTP system, however we would like to roll this out gradually when convenient for our staff.

Our plan is therefore:

- Setup Exchange 2013 to retrieve email via POP Connector **- Done**
- Setup Exchange 2013 to send **ALL** mail via a SmartHost **- Issues**

I have set the domains in Mail Flow > Accepted Domains to Internal Relay, enabled a Smart Host for * as the domain name, and disabled/deleted the accounts that are not setup yet; however Exchange just bounces the emails with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the issue - everything was working as expected; however Outlook had cached the email address I was sending a test to, and causing the issue. Deleting my .NK2 file fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Do all sent emails fail or only those to the users of the same domain not yet transferred?

It it's all emails to any external domain failing then check the authentication setting in the send connector first - most of the time missing authentication there is the problem.

Comment: Hi there, All other emails send fine, I have now found the issue - everything was working as expected; however Outlook had cached the email address I was sending a test to, and causing the issue. Deleting my .NK2 file fixed this.